# Flight BA677 31 july 2016 Istanbul - London

Tags: british-airways

I need to find arrival time in London Heathrow of the BA 677 flight on 31 july 2016.
Can somebody help me? i tried flightstats and other websites but historical flight status check is not free.
Thank you,

Takoz

Comment: I cannot check it free of charge on the flightAware or flightstats.